# iOS: Memory leak codes

Tags: ios, objective-c

Can someone tell me why the following code leaks memory under ARC? I tested them with Instruments and it shows me they cause a memory leak, but I don't know how to fix them ?

```
static inline NSString* cachePathForKey(NSString* directory, NSString* key) {
    return [directory stringByAppendingPathComponent:key]; //leak
}

@property (nonatomic,strong) NSMutableData *postBody;

    if (![self postBody]) {
        [self setPostBody:[NSMutableData data]]; //leak
    }
```

Another question:The instruments shows me the "**All Heap Allocations**" and "**All Anonymous VM**" **Live Bytes**. And for example if an app occupies over 80M(for example), it will crash. Then 80M means **All Heap Allocations** or **Both** ?

**UPDATE:**

As mentioned in one of my comments below, I am now working on change non-ARC ASIHttpRequest to ARC mode. And leaks come. Take ASIInputStream for example:

```
+ (id)inputStreamWithData:(NSData *)data request:(ASIHTTPRequest *)theRequest {
    ASIInputStream *theStream = [[self alloc] init]; //leak 42%
    [theStream setRequest:theRequest];
    NSInputStream *is = [NSInputStream inputStreamWithData:data]; //leak 58%
    [theStream setStream:is];
    return theStream;
}
```

Comment: I doesn't seem like a leak to me!

Comment: How is it telling you that they cause a memory leak?

Comment: Is this called in a background thread?

Comment: @ClayBridges the tool show me the red leak flag, and then I open the call tree, then I locate above codes.

Comment: @ClayBridges the first shows percent 45.8%

Answer (score 0):

This is a shot in the dark, but on the C function, you could try this

```
__attribute__((ns_returns_autoreleased))
static inline NSString* cachePathForKey(NSString* directory, NSString* key) {
    return [directory stringByAppendingPathComponent:key]; //leak
}
```

Cf. Clang [docs](http://clang.llvm.org/docs/AutomaticReferenceCounting.html#unretained-return-values) for more info. You might also try getting rid of `static inline` and seeing if that helps.

Comment: no, all do not work. I am now really confused about where the leaks come from :(
I am now working on change non-ARC ASIHttpRequest to ARC mode. And leaks come. Take ASIInputStream for example: `
+ (id)inputStreamWithData:(NSData *)data request:(ASIHTTPRequest *)theRequest
{
 ASIInputStream *theStream = [[self alloc] init]; //leak 42%
 [theStream setRequest:theRequest];
    NSInputStream *is = [NSInputStream inputStreamWithData:data]; //leak 58%
 [theStream setStream:is]; 
 return theStream;
}
`

Comment: @ZhaoRocky I took the liberty to put that info in an update to your question above.

Answer (score 0):

If you are mixing ARC and non-ARC code, then it's hard to advise you without seeing the big picture. I don't know what your skill level is, but I'd steer novices away from attempting such mixing.

I tested a piece of your code by putting it in a new *Empty* iOS application; looks like this:

[image]

Here's my complete AppDelegate implementation, which does nothing but continually run your `cachePathForKey` function.

```
#import "AppDelegate.h"

@implementation AppDelegate

static inline NSString* cachePathForKey(NSString* directory, NSString* key) {
    return [directory stringByAppendingPathComponent:key]; //leak
}

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    while (YES) {
        @autoreleasepool {
            NSString *s = cachePathForKey(@"/my/fake/dir", @"key");
        }
    }

    return YES;
}

@end
```

I run it Xcode, Product > Profile, and when Instruments starts up, I choose Memory > Leaks. It finds no problems. You might try building up from scratch like that, and seeing if you can find problems that way.

Another technique would be to make a copy of your project (or branch; I *strongly* recommend version control, and particularly `git`). Then start stripping out code until you get down to a very minimal bit of code that still leaks. You could then post that code somewhere; [github](http://github.com) is common, either as a small chunk -- a [gist](https://help.github.com/articles/creating-gists) -- or as a full Xcode project.

Either way, top-down or bottom-up, it's frustrating, and laborious, like a difficult scientific discovery, or an elusive police investigation. But tackling these kind of problems with dogged determination is a huge part of being a software developer. And there's a very helpful community out here. Good luck.